# Creating a plugin for outlook with VS 2008

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, office-addins

I've created an outlook add-in using Visual Studio 2008.  What I want to do is add a menu item to the right click context menu of an email item.  Does anyone have a sample or two of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you should take a look at [this guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2007/01/03/vsto-for-outlook-2007-building-the-add-in-part-2.aspx).

By the way, it almost always pays off to visit www.outlookcode.com/ when dealing with Outlook.